# Как сделать так чтобы после ввода команды он ждал, нового ввода, запомнил ее и вставил в функцию, Aiogram Telegram Bot

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть Telegram BOT на aiogram, который после ввода определенной команды, он ждал нового ввода и не выполнял функцию пока не пользователь что то не напишет, а после взял ввод от пользователя, и вставил это в функцию. Вот кусок кода:

```py
@dp.message_handler(is_owner=True, commands=['text'])
    async def likes_post(message: types.Message):
    
        if message.text == "/like":
            @dp.message_handler(is_owner=True, content_types=['text'])
            async def likes_post_1(message: types.Message):
                try:
                    message.reply("Ведите название аккаунта instagramа:")
                    text = message.text()
                except:
                    message.reply(f"Название аккаунта instagramа: {message.text}")
        await message.reply("Проверьте название аккаунта instagramа:")
        my_bot = InstagramBot(username, password)
        my_bot.login()
        time.sleep(4)
        my_bot.put_many_likes(f"https://www.instagram.com/{message.text}/")
        path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), (f'{message.text}.txt'))
        os.remove(path) 
        path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), (f'{message.text}_set.txt'))
        os.remove(path)
        await message.answer ("Готово")
    
@dp.message_handler(is_owner=True, commands=["hashtag"], content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
    async def hash_tag(message: types.Message):
        await message.answer("Напиши любой #")
        time.sleep(5)
        my_bot = InstagramBot(username, password)
        my_bot.login()
        time.sleep(10)
        my_bot.like_photo_by_hashtag(message.text)
        await message.answer ("Готово")
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать FSM.

Пример кода:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext

class Start(StatesGroup): # Создаём класс.
    start_name= State()



@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=None)
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Как тебя зовут?')
    await Start.start_name.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Start.start_name)
async def namee(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    name = message.text
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=f'Спасибо за ответ\n '
                                                  f'Тебя зовут: {name}')
```

Это только пример кода

Answer (score 0):

Для подобной задачи можно использовать [FSM](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html).
И я бы заменил `if message.text == "/like":` на полноценный хендлер.

Comment: Это как "полноценный хендлер" ?

Comment: ```@dp.message_handler(commands=['like'])```

Comment: Если я делаю так : @dp.message_handler(commands=['like']) то у меня срабатывает
my_bot.put_many_likes(f"https://www.instagram.com/{message.text}/")
И {message.text} идет не после команды like, а сам like, как это можно по фиксить?

Comment: @АлександрСмагин для этого как раз и FSM существуют. Нужно просто ставить стейт и ждать ссылку после выполнения команды /like